# How can i make this SQL Query simpler/shorter?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have designed a following sql query to get the total number of visits done in december.

```
select q.MonthName, count(q.MonthName) as TotalVisit  from
(
SELECT DATENAME( MONTH,v.VisitDate) as MonthName     
FROM Visits v
INNER JOIN Assignments a ON a.AssignmentID = v.AssignmentID
WHERE a.ClientID IN (33,67)
AND v.VisitDate BETWEEN '01/12/2013' AND '31/12/2013' 
)q
group by q.MonthName
```

**Result:**

```
MonthName   TotalVisit

December    164
```

Can i get the same results by writing a single query without using inner query in SQL SEVER 2008?

Comment: Please comment your question.  It will be taken more seriously and more people will help if done so in the first place.  http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the outer query is unnecessary. This should give the same results:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,v.VisitDate) as MonthName, count(*) as TotalVisit
FROM Visits v
INNER JOIN Assignments a ON a.AssignmentID = v.AssignmentID
WHERE a.ClientID IN (33,67)
AND v.VisitDate BETWEEN '01/12/2013' AND '31/12/2013' 
group by DATENAME(MONTH,v.VisitDate)
```

It works because your "count()" function is really just counting records. So there is no difference between count(*) and count(MonthName).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATENAME( MONTH,v.VisitDate) as MonthName,
  COUNT(*) AS TotalVisit
FROM Visits v
INNER JOIN Assignments a ON a.AssignmentID = v.AssignmentID
WHERE a.ClientID IN (33,67)
  AND v.VisitDate BETWEEN '01/12/2013' AND '31/12/2013' 
GROUP BY DATENAME( MONTH,v.VisitDate)
```

Comment: Your SQL doesn't work. COUNT(q.MonthName) no longer exists outside the context of the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have it done in your inner query.  Just a couple of changes:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,v.VisitDate) as MonthName
,COUNT(v.ID) AS Visits  
FROM Visits v
INNER JOIN Assignments a ON a.AssignmentID = v.AssignmentID
WHERE a.ClientID IN (33,67)
AND (v.VisitDate >= '01/12/2013' AND  v.VisitDate <= '31/12/2013') --changed this for performance
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,v.VisitDate)
```

Comment: Your "performance enhancement" has no effect. As long as the BETWEEN statement is logically correct for his use case, it will produce the exact same query plan as using the "<=" and ">=" comparisons.

Source: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/forum/threads/which-is-faster-between-or-and.12165/

Comment: @64BitBob I thought I had read at some point that BETWEEN doesn't use indexes properly.  Might have been a wild dream after a long night of coding.  Thanks for the tip!